# Trying to implement Lazy Loading with FancyTree

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, ajax

So I'm trying to implement a Tree Structure using [FancyTree](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree). I've gotten the tree to display, but I want to implement lazy loading, but I'm having some trouble.

Page:

```
<apex:component controller="TreeNodeViewController">

    ...        

    <apex:inputHidden id="nodeIdField" value="{!nodeId}" />
    <apex:outputText id="test" value="{!loadedNode}" />

    <apex:actionFunction name="getChildren" action="{!getNodeJSON}" oncomplete="console.log('first')">
        <apex:param name="nodeId" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <!-- Add code to initialize the tree when the document is loaded: -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        // Attach the fancytree widget to an existing <div id="tree"> element
        // and pass the tree options as an argument to the dynatree() function:
        $("#tree").fancytree({
            checkbox: {!selectable},
            generateIds: false,
            selectMode: 3,
            source: {!JsonString},
            select: function(event, data) {
                ...
            },
            lazyLoad: function(event, data){
                var nId = data.node.key;

                jQuery(document.getElementById("{!$Component.nodeIdField}")).val(nId);
                getChildren(document.getElementById("{!$Component.nodeIdField}").value);

                children = '{!loadedNode}';

                console.log('second');

                var arr = JSON.parse(children);
                data.result = arr;


            },

        });
    });
    </script>

    <!-- Add a <div> element where the tree should appear: -->
    <div id="tree"> </div>

</apex:component>
```

Controller:

```
public class TreeNodeViewController {

    public Boolean selectable {get; set;}

    public String selectNodeKeys {get; set;}

    public String loadedNode {get; set;}

    {
        selectable = false;
        selectNodeKeys = 'No value selected';
        loadedNode = '';
    }

    public String jsonData {get; set;}


    public String getJsonString() 
    {
        if (jsonData == null){
            jsonData = NodeDisplay.getTreeJSON();
        }
        return jsonData;
    }

    public String nodeId {get; set;}

    public void getNodeJSON()
    {
        String nId = ''+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('nodeId');
        String value = NodeDisplay.getNodeJSON(nId);
        loadedNode = value;
        System.debug(value);
        // return value;

    }

}
```

NodeDisplay class:

```
public class NodeDisplay 
{

    private static Map <Id, Node__c> allNodes {get; set;}

    private static List<Node__c> rootNodes {get; set;}

    private static Map <Id, List<Node__c>> idToSubNodes {get; set;}

    // Global JSON generator
    private static JSONGenerator gen {get; set;}

    static 
    {
        init();
    }

    private static void init()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static String getTreeJSON() {
        gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartArray();

        for(Node__c n : rootNodes)
        {
            NodeNode node = createNode(n.Id);
            convertNodeToJSON(node);
        }
        gen.writeEndArray();
        return gen.getAsString();
    }

    public static String getNodeJSON(String objId)
    {
        Id i;

        try
        {
            i = Id.valueOf(objId);
        }
        catch(StringException e)
        {
            return '[]';
        }

        List<Node__c> subList = idToSubNodes.get(i);

        gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

        for(Node__c n : subList)
        {
            NodeNode node = createNode(n.Id);
            convertNodeToJSON(node);
        }

        return gen.getAsString();

    }

    private static NodeNode createNode(Id objId) {
        NodeNode n = new NodeNode();
        ...
        return n;
    }

    private static void convertNodeToJSON(NodeNode node)
    {
        gen.writeStartObject();

            gen.writeStringField('title', node.name);
            gen.writeStringField('key', node.id);
            gen.writeBooleanField('unselectable', false);
            gen.writeBooleanField('expanded', false);
            gen.writeBooleanField('folder', true);
            if (node.hasChildren)
            {
                gen.writeNullField('children');
                gen.writeBooleanField('lazy', true);
            }

        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

    public class NodeNode {
        ...
    }

}
```

I know it's a lot of code, and I tried to take out the less important sections. The `loadedNode` field debugs correctly, but it doesn't get passed to the lazyload function correctly. After using some print statements, I found out that it looks like the lazyload tries to get the value of the `loadedNode` field before the `getChildren` function finishes ('second' prints before 'first'). This looks like just something that has to do with the way FancyTree does it's lazy loading, so I'm not sure if there is a way around this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a closer look at how to set [Lazy Loading](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#lazy-loading), after which you might want to look at the link to the Tutorial Load Data that's directly underneath it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but here's how I'm doing it.

```
$(function () {
    // Create the tree inside the <div id="tree"> element.
    $("#tree").fancytree({
        source: { url: "/Home/GetData", cache: true }
        , checkbox: true
        , icons: false
        , cache: true
        , lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
            var node = data.node;
            data.result = {
                url: "/Home/GetTreeViewData/" + node.key
                , data: { mode: "children", parent: node.key }
                , cache: true
            };
        }
        , selectMode: 3
        , select: function (event, data) { 
        }
        , strings: {
            loading: "Grabbing places and events…",
            loadError: "Load error!"
        },
    })
});
```

Basically, if you were to browse to mysite/Home/GetData, it returns a json result that looks like this

```
[{"key":1,"title":"Accommodations","lazy":true,"parentId":null},{"key":5,"title":"Attractions","lazy":false,"parentId":null},{"key":6,"title":"Dining","lazy":false,"parentId":null},{"key":7,"title":"Entertainment","lazy":false,"parentId":null},{"key":18,"title":"1","lazy":true,"parentId":null},{"key":23,"title":"2","lazy":true,"parentId":null}]
```

Now say you expand the first node, it's ID in the database is 1, and any children underneath it have a column called parentId with a value of one. When you browse to mysite/Home/GetTreeViewData/1 you get this

```
[{"key":2,"title":"Hotels","lazy":false,"parentId":1},{"key":3,"title":"Bed \u0026 Breakfast","lazy":false,"parentId":1}]
```

So I just pull the node.key as my Id and use it to load the children. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
lazyLoad: function(event, data){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    data.result = dfd;   
    var nId = data.node.key;
    jQuery(document.getElementById(" {!$Component.nodeIdField}")).val(nId);
    getChildren(document.getElementById("{!$Component.nodeIdField}").value);
    children = '{!loadedNode}';
    console.log('second');
    var arr = JSON.parse(children);
    dfd.resolve(arr);
},
```